# display a specific image file from a folder in php code (the image should be displayed the number of times the user specified in quantity field)

Tags: php

How to get an image from the food items folder and display it the amount of times the user has specified in the quantity input field?

The image file extensions are all png.

We are not using a database.

my project structure looks like

Project Folder

---Images Folder

---order.php

---submit-order.php

Below is the submit-order.php file.

The order.php file displays the front-end

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //set variable for food and quantity
    $food = "";
    $quantity = "";
    $price = 0;
    $image = "";
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // check if there is a value for quantity and food
        if(!empty( $_POST["Food"]) && !empty($_POST["quantity"])){
    
            $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
            $food = $_POST["Food"];
            // calculate the price and get the images
            if($food == "apple" && $quantity <= 4){
                //calculate the price of the item
                $price = $quantity * 5.00;
                //display an image
                for($i=0;$i<$quantity;$i++)
                {
                    $image = "<img src='/Food Items/apple.jpg' style='width=50px; height=50px; 
                margin-left: 10px' alt='apple'>";
                }
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Order successful R{$price} is your total price. Here is what 
                 you ordered: {$image}";
                // display the index file after user submits input
                header('location: geu_order.php');
                // display the pictures of the item
                }else{
                $_SESSION['msg'] = "Sorry we do not have {$quantity} {$food} in stock";
                // display the index file after user submits input
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Change `$image =` to `$image .=`. then it adds the image tag to the string each time the loop runs, rather than assigning a new value (and thus overwriting the previous value!). (N.B. You didn't actually specify what problem(s) you're having, but presumably it's only displaying one item, which is a consequence of the problem I've just pointed out...if you have any other issues you should make it clear. In future when posting, always explain the problem as well as just what you want, it's not always obvious from just reading the code.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback ADyson. I have implemented the solution. It displays the picture the number of times a user has specified in the quantity input field. The other problem I'm facing is that it does not show actual images from the images folder

Comment: What do you mean? You said it displays the picture, but then in the second sentence you're saying it doesn't show the actual image...those two statements seem to contradict each other. Either it displays the picture or it doesn't. Can you be clearer about the specific issue, and what you want to happen instead?

Comment: sorry about that, the image placeholders (the image errors when there should be a picture there but the link is not getting it from the folder) display which means the loop works.
Please have a look at it here
https://i.imgur.com/lSjzzpr.png
I would like the images from the folder to display

Comment: If you look in the network tool in the browser's developer tools when you're trying to load the page, what response do you see for those image files? I'd guess probably 404, or maybe 403. The response code is important because it lets us know something about the reason why it's failing. 404 (Not Found) means the URL is wrong (so probably you got the relative path wrong - if I was you I wouldn't use spaces in the folder name), whereas 403 (Forbidden) means it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Thank you so much it displays the images: `<img src='./FoodItems/apple.jpg' style='width=100px; height=100px; margin-left: 10px' alt='apple'>`
I had missed the period preceding the /FoodItems